# increment another model field using django signals

Tags: python, django, django-models, relational-database, django-signals

I have two models, **A** and **B**. I want to increment the value in one field of **model A** whenever i insert another value in **model B**.  I am using post_save signals but i keep getting this error "**'update_fields' is an invalid keyword argument for this function"**

below is my code thank you for your help.

```
class Sales(models.Model):
    id = models.AutoField(primary_key=True) 
    order_details = models.ForeignKey(GeneralConsulting)    
    medication_name_id = models.ForeignKey(Medication_List)
    dosage = models.CharField(max_length=10,  blank=True)
    duration = models.CharField(max_length=10,  blank=True)
    quantity = models.IntegerField(default=0)
    ...


@receiver(signals.post_save, sender=Sales)
class Product(models.Model):
    id = models.AutoField(primary_key=True)
    product_name = models.ForeignKey(Medication_List)
    description = models.TextField(blank=True)
    supplier = models.ManyToManyField(Supplier, blank=True)
    expiration_date = models.DateField(blank=False, null=True )
    ...
    quantity_sold = models.IntegerField(default=0)  
    minimum_stock_level = models.IntegerField(default=1)



    def add_on(self, sender, created, instance, update_fields, **kwargs ):
        if created or update_fields is 'quantity':    
            b = Product.objects.get(product_name_id=instance.id)
            if b.quantity_sold + instance.quantity <= b.initial_qty:
                b.quantity_sold = b.quantity_sold + instance.quantity
            b.save(update_fields=['quantity_sold'])
```

So all i want to do is to increase the value in the Product.quantity_sold field 
whenever a new sale is added.

Kindly help, i am quite new with django signals. Is there a better way to do this? Thanks

Comment: Can you change `@receiver(signals.post_save, sender=Sales)` => `@receiver(models.signals.post_save, sender=Sales)` ?

Comment: hmmm, no luck with that. The same error pops up again

Answer (score 0):

What about overriding the `save` method of the class `Sales`? For example:

```
class Sales(models.Model):
    id = models.AutoField(primary_key=True) 
    order_details = models.ForeignKey(GeneralConsulting)    
    medication_name_id = models.ForeignKey(Medication_List)
    dosage = models.CharField(max_length=10,  blank=True)
    duration = models.CharField(max_length=10,  blank=True)
    quantity = models.IntegerField(default=0)

    def save(self, *args, **kwargs):
        p = Product.objects.get(product_name=self.medication_name_id)
        p.quantity_sold += self.quantity
        p.save()
        super(Sales, self).save(*args, **kwargs)
```

Basically, anytime you have to save a new sale, you increment the relative product's `quantity_sold` before saving. I assumed you get the product related to a sale by the `Medication_List`.

A caveat: you call the `save` method also for updating pre-existing objects. If you plan to update existing sales, you need something more than the code above. Otherwise you'll increment product's `quantity_sold` also for mere sales updates.

Comment: I am a bit confused by your code, i thought `super(Sales, self).save(*args, **kwargs)` will save back to the Sales model, i dont see how that will save to the Product model. Anyway i will try it and see.

Comment: @HamzaBawumia I have just updated my answer. I hope it can help you!

Comment: It didnt work for me, the Product model is already importing Sales model so i cant import the Sales model back into Product model. . This is like a cyclical import error. A imports B and B is importing A again. Lol, Anyway thanks for your trick, i guess i will use it another project.